# Text not showing in html page

Tags: html

All of my other pages work, this is for a school project.  I compared them but there is something wrong with this one.  I don't want to redo it, as I am using it as a template and would like to just use this.
I posted the whole page, just in case you need it. The problem is the two paragraphs do not show up about
Frodo.

```
<html>
<head>
<TITLE>Lord of the Rings: Frodo</TITLE>
<style>
pre{font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;}
pre{font-size:25px;}
pre{color:gold;}

body
{
background-image:url('http://awesomewallpapers.files.wordpress.com/2010/08/one-ring-to-rule-them-all-                1.png');
background-color:#cccccc;
} 

background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-position:topleft; 
a{color:blue;}
a:hover{color:gold;}
a:visited{color:white;}
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-position:center; 

</style>
</head>

<body link="white">
<center>

<hr><A HREF="MoviePage.html">Home</A> <A HREF="Characters.html>Characters</A></hr>

<pre>
    Frodo is the main character in this series, the carrier of the One Ring and the
one who must support its burden.  Frodo goes through many trials through the course of
the movies, some include battles, attacks on his mind and even a near death experience.

    Frodo is the nephew of Bilbo Baggins, the once great adventurer who first brought
the ring to the shire.  He is a friend of Gandalf, whom he speaks with everytime he goes
through the Shire.  Frodo and Bilbo's birthday are on the same day, and hold a massive
party in their name.


</pre>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You really should use `<p>` tags instead of `<pre>`.

Comment: others already replied to your question, anyway i also want you to notice a couple of other things. In the css part included in your html page you included only 2 properties in the body style and left out the others, you should include them as well. Another thing, you defined <body link="white"> and then in the css: a{color:blue;}
a:hover{color:gold;}
a:visited{color:white;} . In a place you are defining a color, in another place another color. Please fix it.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a " mark here:

```
 <a HREF="Characters.html">
```

Chuck that in and all is working fine, have checked it with jsfiddle.  You can see the updated working one here : http://jsfiddle.net/2FBqm/

Comment: Thanks, not using a thingamajig that shows what you need to do, I might get eclipse when I start making games in java, if it supports HTML I might use it when I take web design.  Thanks though, I feel stupid now.

Comment: Happens to everybody don't worry about it :)

Answer (score 1):

You missed a double quote.

```
<hr><A HREF="MoviePage.html">Home</A> <A HREF="Characters.html>Characters</A></hr>
                                                              ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 31; You forgot to close a double quote sign ( " ).

Replace this line with:

```
<hr><A HREF="MoviePage.html">Home</A> <A HREF="Characters.html">Characters</A></hr>
```

BTW, welcome aboard :)